# Partial application of strict constructors

Tags: performance, haskell

Suppose I have

```
data Foo a = Foo !Int a [a] | Bar [a]
```

so the `Foo` constructor is strict in its first argument, which will be unpacked. Suppose further that I'm passing `Foo n` to a higher-order function `f` and that `f` does not get inlined (so `Foo n` is actually passed). The Core I get with `-O2` indicates that `n` gets boxed and then passed to `Foo`, and the result is passed to `f`. My question: would I be better off calling

```
f (\a b -> Foo n a b)
```

to avoid boxing `n`? Or would that lead to some other performance problem?

---

I was actually thinking to define

```
foo' !n = \a b -> Foo n a b
```

and call `f (foo' n)`, which I figured should do the same thing, but I guess it's better to ask specifically.

Comment: As far as I know `Foo n` is transformed to `\ a b -> Foo n a b` by the compiler, because there are no partially applied constructors in the STG-machine.

Comment: @augustss, `Foo` is translated to a strict *function* which calls the real constructor, as far as I can tell. Does further unboxing occur between simplification and STG?

Comment: All I meant was that partially applied constructors are translated to functions.  Then there is another level of translation for strict constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened [GHC Trac ticket 12990](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12990) for this. Reid Barton and Simon Peyton Jones suggested a fix (allowing the wrapper function to be inlined when partially applied), which I submitted as [GHC Phabricator differential D2891](https://phabricator.haskell.org/D2891). The patch has been applied to the master branch and will be included in GHC 8.2.